# How to open bs Modal at right bottom using only typescripts in angular 6?

Tags: angular

I'm trying to fade bs modal at right bottm while pop up the modal using typescripts but it's not working. so where i need to change class?

```
<ng-template #template> 
 <div class="modal-header"> 
   <h4>{{notification?.title}}</h4> 
   <button type="button" class="close pull-right" aria-label="Close" 
     (click)="commonResource.modalRef.hide()"> <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span> </button>
</div>
```

Comment: share your code. what you have tried so far?

Comment: <ng-template #template>
      <div class="modal-header">
        <h4>{{notification?.title}}</h4>
        <button type="button" class="close pull-right" aria-label="Close" (click)="commonResource.modalRef.hide()">
          <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
        </button>
      </div>
</ng-template>
and while clicking the pop up modal using following
this.commonResource.modalRef = this.modalService.show(template, { class:'small'} it's not fade like expected.